# How to use hash function in Python3 to transform an arbitrary string into a fixed-length sequence of alphanumeric symbols?

Tags: python, hash

I have a large number of different sentences written in different languages (French, Ukrainian, English and so on). For each sentence I want to generate audio file with the given sentence being pronounced by a text-to-speech program. Now I need to decide how to name those audio files (one file for each sentence). I thought that it would be elegant if I can infer file name from the sentence. In other words, if I see the sentence, I should be able to computer (infer / derive) the name of audio file in which this sentence is spoken.

I thought that I could use a hash function for that. I would apply a hash function to the string representing the sentence and, as a result, I would get a string (hash) that I can use as a name of the file.

Why not to use the sentence itself as a name? Because sentences can be large and I do not want to have very large file names. Moreover, I do not want to have spaces and other punctuation symbols (as well as strange alphabet symbols) in the names of the files. Finally, I expect that hash will always have the same length which looks nice.

Now is my question: How can I transform an arbitrary unicode string into a sequence of alphanumeric symbols being a hash of the input string in Python3?

I also wonder if there is a danger of getting the same hash for different sentences.

**ADDED:**

I have just realized, that by applying `hash` function to the same string I can get different results for different sessions. This is, obviously, something that I would like to avoid.

Comment: There are several different secure hash and message digest algorithms. Those are the ones included in hashlib https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html

Comment: Encode your strings as UTF-8, pass the resulting bytes to one of the `hashlib` hashes, use the `.hexdigest()` of the hash as your filename.  A 128-bit hash (giving a 32 character filename) should be long enough that you can ignore the possibility of collisions - except in the unlikely case where a sentence happens to be meaningful in more than one language (but with enough of a pronunciation difference that you can't just reuse the audio file).  A language prefix on the string being hashed would eliminate that potential problem.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Use a cryptographic hash function such as SHA-256; [they're available in `hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html). (As you've noticed, `hash` isn't stable between sessions due to `PYTHONHASHSEED`, nor necessarily between Python versions and interpreters.)

I also apply some normalization here, but that may or may not be what you want.

```
import hashlib


def get_filename(sentence: str) -> str:
    # assuming leading/trailing whitespace doesn't matter, nor does case
    sentence_norm = sentence.lower().strip()  
    return hashlib.sha256(sentence_norm.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
```

```
>>> get_filename("Hello, mon ami!")
'c13c197526d17532bd6d9bf3c2ad34486ccb2fcdeadaf7b71c3c67c0f048ecb9'
>>> get_filename("hello, mon ami!   ")
'c13c197526d17532bd6d9bf3c2ad34486ccb2fcdeadaf7b71c3c67c0f048ecb9'
>>>
```

> I also wonder if there is a danger of getting the same hash for different sentences.

No, not until SHA-256 is broken, and if it is, we're all in trouble anyway.

Comment: If there is a large number of sentences, it may be advantageous to split up the filename and create subdirectories, e.g.: `path = Path(audio_dir) / h[0:18] / h[18:36] / h[36:]`

Comment: @Amadan Yes, but that's a different concern (namely that of filesystem effectiveness). I'd probably do `h[:2]/h[2:4]/h`, just so you can get the original hash from the filename without needing to look at directories, and also to retain a suitably small cardinality as far as directories go.